# Google OAuth: how to use a refresh token?

Tags: java, android, google-oauth

I am able to exchange my one time use token from my Android device for an *access token* and a *refresh token*. I am trying to figure out how to use the *refresh token*.

I found [this](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#refresh) which works over an HTTPS request, but I was wondering if there was some where in the Java SDK to handle refreshing?

Comment: Have you checked out the java client library for Google Apps API? https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2

"GoogleCredential takes care of automatically "refreshing" the token, which simply means getting a new access token. This is done by means of a long-lived refresh token, which is typically received along with the access token if you use the "access_type=offline" parameter during the authorization code flow (see GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder.setAccessType(String))"

Comment: I don't use the GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow to generate my token from the device i use the GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mContext, mAccountName,
      scopes); i don't see method for setting access_type

Answer (score 3):

You don’t need to.  Just call GoogleAuthUtil.getToken() before each HTTP conversation, and GoogleAuthUtil will make sure you get one that works, refreshing if necessary.

EDITED: Oh, OK, he's doing this on the server. Here's some java code that uses a refresh token:

```
       String data = "refresh_token=" + mRefreshToken +
                "&client_id=" + Constants.WEB_CLIENT_ID +
                "&client_secret=" + Constants.WEB_CLIENT_SECRET +
                "&grant_type=refresh_token";
        byte[] body = data.getBytes();

        URL url = new URL(Constants.GOOGLE_TOKEN_ENDPOINT);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(body.length);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.getOutputStream().write(body);

        body = XAuth.readStream(conn.getInputStream());
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(new String(body));

        String accessToken = json.optString("access_token");
        if (accessToken == null) {
            throw new Exception("Refresh token yielded no access token");
        }
```

Comment: I am not doing the http requests on the android device. I am exchanging it on the server for offline access

Comment: Why are you embedding server's client secret on a client device?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Google API for for that.

```
JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();
HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();    
GoogleCredential refreshTokenCredential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY).setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT).setClientSecrets(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET).build().setRefreshToken(yourOldToken);
refreshTokenCredential.refreshToken(); //do not forget to call this method
String newAccessToken = refreshTokenCredential.getAccessToken();
```