# how to get refresh token google api using informatica java transformation

Tags: java, google-oauth, informatica

It's the first time to use Informatica java transformation, I need to get the refresh token in google API oauth2 to be able to get the access token using Informatica Java transformation.

my current status is I can get the refresh token manual from google playground using client id and secret id then use it as a parameter in Informatica to get the access token and it has done successfully.
so now I need to skip the manual step and make it from Informatica java code is it possible.

kindly help me and provide me with some examples.

Comment: The Informatica aspect of this is less relevant (apart from general steps needed to configure and deploy any Java transformation in INFA). I would recommend writing your Java code in a proper IDE first, before porting it to an INFA transformation object. The changes should be minimal (e.g. for input/output ports, etc).

Comment: You can start by researching existing answers to questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725736/google-oauth-how-to-use-a-refresh-token), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63388710/google-api-refresh-token-and-access-token-questions-java-be-web-app), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50903787/how-to-get-an-access-token-using-a-refresh-token-in-java) - and probably others also.

Comment: You can check my answer here. You can use a HTTP transformation first to get the token and then use that token as input to your API java transformation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63295470/informatica-how-to-post-json-data-with-bearer-token-in-header